# calculating the the input impedance with the effect of ro

Tags: transistors, power-electronics, input-impedance, emitter-follower

[image: emitter follower configuration]

[image: calculating zb with the resistance of ro]

How could he calculate zb with the effect of resistance of ro?

[image: calculating zb without the resistance ro]

Here he calculated zb without the effect of ro and i have understood that.

Comment: So what is the difference? See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/532282/152903 If you wanted to improve your question, then edit the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book already gives you part of the answer which is when \$r_0\$ is set to infinity: why restarting from scratch as in *Jan*'s answer? The easiest way is to capitalize on this intermediate result and apply the extra-element theorem or [EET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_element_theorem) defined by Dr. Middlebrook. By calculating the resistance value "seen" across \$r_0\$'s terminals when the excitation is turned off (\$R_d\$) and when the response is nulled (\$R_n\$) you can compute a coefficient affecting the original result to obtain the answer. By excitation, I imply the current generator you need to determine \$Z_b\$ in your drawing.

To determine \$R_d\$ and \$R_n\$, you have the below two drawings:

[image]

In the left side, as the excitation is turned off, there is no base current and the resistance \$R_d\$ is simply the sum of the emitter and collector resistances. For \$R_n\$, you first determine the base current and then the voltage \$V_T\$ which depends on \$I_T\$. Once you have the resistance you want, you apply the EET which states:

\$R_{in}=R_{in,ref}\frac{1+\frac{R_n}{r_0}}{1+\frac{R_d}{r_0}}\$

with \$R_{in,ref}\$ being the original formula given in the book while neglecting \$r_0\$. I have built a quick Mathcad sheet which compares the EET result and the one given in the book. They are delivering the exact same result:

[image]

The EET equation complies with the so-called *low-entropy* format where you immediately see that if \$r_0\$ approaches infinity, then the result returns to the formula given in the book. The formula given in the book also shows that bringing \$r_0\$ infinite returns the expression to the first one but in a less obvious way in my opinion. The EET is part of the fast analytical circuit techniques toolbox as described in the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371) I published on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

> First, I will present a general method of finding your transfer function. I will use [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) to do it.

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY8Q5M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_\text{i}=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_7\\
\\
\text{I}_7=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\beta\cdot\text{I}_2+\text{I}_9\\
\\
\text{I}_9=\text{I}_5+\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_8\\
\\
\text{I}_8=\beta\cdot\text{I}_2+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\text{I}_\text{i}+\text{I}_{10}\\
\\
0=\text{I}_3+\text{I}_6+\text{I}_{10}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\text{I}_6=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_6}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Now, it is not hard to solve for \$\text{I}_7\$:

$$\text{I}_7=\tag3$$

```
(Vi (R4 R5 + R4 R6 + R5 R6 + R2 (R3 + R5 + R6) + R5 R6 β + 
   R3 (R4 + R5 + R5 β)))/(
R2 R4 (R3 + R5) + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) R6 + R3 R5 R6 (1 + β) + 
 R3 R4 (R5 + R6 + R5 β))
```

In order to find \$(3)\$, I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[1]:=FullSimplify[
 Solve[{Ii == I1 + I7, I7 == I2 + I4, I4 == \[Beta]*I2 + I9, 
   I9 == I5 + I6, I3 == I2 + I8, I8 == \[Beta]*I2 + I5, 
   I1 == Ii + I10, 0 == I3 + I6 + I10, I1 == Vi/R1, 
   I2 == (Vi - V1)/R2, I3 == V1/R3, I4 == (Vi - V2)/R4, 
   I5 == (V2 - V1)/R5, I6 == V2/R6}, {Ii, I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, I7, 
   I8, I9, I10, V1, V2}]]

Out[1]={{Ii -> Vi (1/R1 + (
      R3 R4 + R3 R5 + R4 R5 + R4 R6 + R5 R6 + R2 (R3 + R5 + R6) + 
       R5 (R3 + R6) \[Beta])/(
      R2 R4 (R3 + R5) + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) R6 + 
       R3 R5 R6 (1 + \[Beta]) + R3 R4 (R5 + R6 + R5 \[Beta]))), 
  I1 -> Vi/R1, 
  I2 -> ((R4 (R3 + R5) + (R4 + R5) R6) Vi)/(
   R2 R4 (R3 + R5) + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) R6 + R3 R5 R6 (1 + \[Beta]) + 
    R3 R4 (R5 + R6 + R5 \[Beta])), 
  I3 -> (Vi (R6 (R2 + R5 + R5 \[Beta]) + R4 (R5 + R6 + R5 \[Beta])))/(
   R2 R4 (R3 + R5) + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) R6 + R3 R5 R6 (1 + \[Beta]) + 
    R3 R4 (R5 + R6 + R5 \[Beta])), 
  I4 -> (Vi (R2 (R3 + R5 + R6) + R5 (R3 + (R3 + R6) \[Beta])))/(
   R2 R4 (R3 + R5) + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) R6 + R3 R5 R6 (1 + \[Beta]) + 
    R3 R4 (R5 + R6 + R5 \[Beta])), 
  I5 -> -((Vi (R3 R4 - R2 R6 + R4 (R3 + R6) \[Beta]))/(
    R2 R4 (R3 + R5) + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) R6 + R3 R5 R6 (1 + \[Beta]) + 
     R3 R4 (R5 + R6 + R5 \[Beta]))), 
  I6 -> (Vi (R2 (R3 + R5) - R4 R5 \[Beta] + 
      R3 (R4 + R5 + R5 \[Beta])))/(
   R2 R4 (R3 + R5) + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) R6 + R3 R5 R6 (1 + \[Beta]) + 
    R3 R4 (R5 + R6 + R5 \[Beta])), 
  I7 -> (Vi (R4 R5 + R4 R6 + R5 R6 + R2 (R3 + R5 + R6) + 
      R5 R6 \[Beta] + R3 (R4 + R5 + R5 \[Beta])))/(
   R2 R4 (R3 + R5) + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) R6 + R3 R5 R6 (1 + \[Beta]) + 
    R3 R4 (R5 + R6 + R5 \[Beta])), 
  I8 -> (Vi (-R3 R4 + R2 R6 + R5 (R4 + R6) \[Beta]))/(
   R2 R4 (R3 + R5) + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) R6 + R3 R5 R6 (1 + \[Beta]) + 
    R3 R4 (R5 + R6 + R5 \[Beta])), 
  I9 -> (Vi (R2 (R3 + R5 + R6) - R4 (R5 + R6) \[Beta] + 
      R3 (R5 - R4 \[Beta] + R5 \[Beta])))/(
   R2 R4 (R3 + R5) + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) R6 + R3 R5 R6 (1 + \[Beta]) + 
    R3 R4 (R5 + R6 + R5 \[Beta])), 
  I10 -> -((
    Vi (R4 R5 + R4 R6 + R5 R6 + R2 (R3 + R5 + R6) + R5 R6 \[Beta] + 
       R3 (R4 + R5 + R5 \[Beta])))/(
    R2 R4 (R3 + R5) + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) R6 + R3 R5 R6 (1 + \[Beta]) + 
     R3 R4 (R5 + R6 + R5 \[Beta]))), 
  V1 -> (R3 Vi (R6 (R2 + R5 + R5 \[Beta]) + 
      R4 (R5 + R6 + R5 \[Beta])))/(
   R2 R4 (R3 + R5) + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) R6 + R3 R5 R6 (1 + \[Beta]) + 
    R3 R4 (R5 + R6 + R5 \[Beta])), 
  V2 -> (R6 Vi (R2 (R3 + R5) - R4 R5 \[Beta] + 
      R3 (R4 + R5 + R5 \[Beta])))/(
   R2 R4 (R3 + R5) + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) R6 + R3 R5 R6 (1 + \[Beta]) + 
    R3 R4 (R5 + R6 + R5 \[Beta]))}}
```

---

Now, when we want to find \$\text{Z}_\text{b}\$ we need to take look at:

$$\text{Z}_\text{b}=\lim_{\text{R}_4\to\infty}\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{I}_7}\tag4$$

So, we find:

$$\text{Z}_\text{b}=\text{R}_2+\frac{\text{R}_3\left(\text{R}_5\left(1+\beta\right)+\text{R}_6\right)}{\text{R}_3+\text{R}_5+\text{R}_6}\tag5$$

In order to find \$(5)\$, I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[2]:=FullSimplify[
 Limit[(Vi)/((
    Vi (R4 R5 + R4 R6 + R5 R6 + R2 (R3 + R5 + R6) + R5 R6 \[Beta] + 
       R3 (R4 + R5 + R5 \[Beta])))/(
    R2 R4 (R3 + R5) + R2 (R3 + R4 + R5) R6 + R3 R5 R6 (1 + \[Beta]) + 
     R3 R4 (R5 + R6 + R5 \[Beta]))), R4 -> Infinity]]

Out[2]=R2 + (R3 (R5 + R6 + R5 \[Beta]))/(R3 + R5 + R6)
```