# Extra element theorem

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, transfer-function

I don't understand the reasoning behind solving for the \$Z_{out,0}\$ term in the extra-element theorem (EET) in this textbook example. For clarity, the full EET is that any transfer function can be expressed as \$H(s)=H_0(s)\frac{1+Z_{out,0} / Z}{1+Z_{in,0} / Z}\$. The \$Z_{out,0}\$ term is found in the following way: in place of the extra element [here the capacitor], place a test voltage source *without nulling the input source*. Then solve for the ratio \$V_x/I_x\$ such that the output [here the drain voltage] is 0.

In the below example, solving for this ratio is in general not possible since the output can't be zero while \$V_x\$ is nonzero. The example says this requires an "infinite current" which I don't understand. The current \$I_x\$ seems to actually be forced to be equal to \$g_mV_{in}\$ since if the drain is at 0 then no current goes through the resistor. What's going on here?

[image]

Comment: You apply the extra-element theorem or EET to a circuit in which an (extra) element makes the analysis difficult because of its presence. You then write a first intermediate transfer function with this element made 0 (a short circuit) or brought to infinity (removed). Then, in both cases, you have to temporarily disconnect the extra element and determine a resistance "seen" from its connecting terminals in two conditions: \$r_d\$ when the excitation is zeroed and \$r_n\$ when the output is a null. Once done, you apply the EET formula and you have your final expression.

Comment: In your case, since you want an impedance, the stimulus is the current source while the response is the voltage across its terminals. If \$C_F\$ is most likely the selected extra element, you determine \$r_d\$ while the current source is zeroed (removed) and \$r_n\$ when the current source is replaced by a short circuit (degenerate case). You can look at some of the examples I solved using the EET in [SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/532294/calculating-the-the-input-impedance-with-the-effect-of-ro/532552#532552) (search for EET).

Comment: By the way, the original EET formula is defined as follows: \$Z=Z_{\infty}\frac{1+\frac{r_n}{Z}}{1+\frac{r_d}{Z}}\$ if you solve the intermediate transfer function considering the extra element infinite. And it you short the extra element instead, the expression becomes: \$Z=Z_0\frac{1+\frac{Z}{r_n}}{1+\frac{Z}{r_d}}\$. Also, it is important to understand that a *null* is not a short circuit. Rather, it means that the stimulus does not propagate in the circuit and there is a zero ac response.

Comment: @VerbalKint It seems this question was a continuation of an exercise, where EET was first applied with regards to \$C_F\$, now it wants the same for \$C_B\$, the "capacitor \$C_B\$ from node B to ground" (not depicted). The Figure 6.48 (a) shows such capacitor being replaced by a voltage source \$V_1\$, as part of a solution step. Maybe this clarification aids to your contribution? I'm not the question author, but this was my interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with EET, but this is my interpretation of the problem. You can ignore the entirety of the circuit and focus only on the output voltage (here \$V_o\$) with added \$V_1\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRqBN6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Without the "distractions" from the rest of the circuit, you can note the additional source \$V_1\$ causes the relation \$V_o=V_1\$. You state your goal as "solve for \$Z_{out,0}=V_1/I_1\$, such that \$V_o\$ is zero". Well, if we enforce the constraint \$V_o=0\$ in this circuit, it must follow \$V_1=0\$, therefore \$Z_{out,0}=0\$.

The solution mention to "infinite current" arises if we were to try and force \$V_1\neq0\$. In this situation, regardless, it still follows that \$V_o=V_1\$ so therefore \$Z_{out,0}=0\$, and the only way one can get a zero ratio from a nonzero numerator (\$V_1\$), is to have an infinite denominator (\$I_1\$). This seems to be an obtuse attempt at a [proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction), being the original proposition \$V_1=0\$ assumed to be false.